# Drupal login form customize

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-forms

Hi i have used this code

```
<?php
    $elements = drupal_get_form("user_login");
    $form = drupal_render($elements);

    echo $form;
?>
```

to get the default Drupal login form for my site but I need to customize the HTML, I have found some pages in module/users but did not understand how to customize the structure.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @pamatt : I am trying to create a login form for users with username and password and used the above form, but I want to customize the structure of the form . Where do i get the structure of the form so that i could customize it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in template.php

```
function themename_theme() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'corporateclean') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',

  );
```

and create a template folder and within that create a file user-login.tpl.php and in this file you can put your html and could customize drupal login

Answer (score 2):

The user login form for Drupal is built by the `user_login` function in `user.module` using [Drupal Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7). If you need to customize it, you should do it using hook_form_alter() in your module

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id=='user_login') {

     // YOUR CUSTOM CODE FOR THE FORM GOES HERE

  }
}
```

** EDIT, AFTER YOUR COMMENT **

You don't need to call the `YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_alter()` function: Drupal does that for you via the hook mechanism everytime it needs to build a form, and, when `$form_id=='user_login'`, it modifies the login form to allow your customization. The way Drupal does that is discussed in detail in drupal.org, just follow the link I wrote at the beginning of this answer.

The user login form is declared this way in `user.module`:

```
// Display login form:
  $form['name'] = array('#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Username'),
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['name']['#description'] = t('Enter your @s username.', array('@s' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')));
  $form['pass'] = array('#type' => 'password',
    '#title' => t('Password'),
    '#description' => t('Enter the password that accompanies your username.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['#validate'] = user_login_default_validators();
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Log in'));
```

The $form array is passed by reference to your `hook_form_alter()` before being rendered, allowing for customization. So, let's say that you want to change the label of the textfield for the user name from "Username" to "Name of the User", you write

```
$form['name']['#title'] = t("Name of the User");
```

in your custom code. If you want to add another field to the form (a textarea, for example), you do

```
$form['otherfield'] = array(
  '#title' => t('My new custom textarea'),
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#description' => t("A description of what this area is for"),
  '#cols' => 10,
  '#rows' => 3,
  '#weight' => 20,
);
```

and Drupal will add the field to the user login form.

There are many different kind of fields and properties that you can customize this way: I encourage you to fully read the Form API documentation. This way you let Drupal take care of form generation, translation, rendering, validation and submission, also permitting to other modules to manipulate your form if needed.

I hope it's clear, have a good day.

Comment: Hi pamatt  I have two quiestions in mind first : how do i call the function in my page.tpl.php page if the function is axiton _form_alter secondly is that in the place of my custom code should i place the total html ??

Comment: Hey @pamatt could you please send me your mail id so that I could share you some code ?

Comment: Ron there is no way I can send you my e-mail other than publishing it on Stack Overflow, which I am not going to do. Anyway, this forum is to share problems and solutions, you can safely share your code here: other people may drop in and contribute to the answer you look for, and other people may find the same answer you are looking for.

Comment: Hi pamatt I have created the block.tpl.php and with that i can call my custom form by hooking it with menu but in that case drupals default functionality is not working . Check this url http://www.esolzdemos.com/lab4/axonconnect and if i run http://www.esolzdemos.com/lab4/axonconnect/user/password the password field for forget password does not arrive .

Comment: You get Drupal's default functionality if you use Drupal default form. What is your block.tpl.php doing? What do you exactly need to customize the login form for?

Comment: In my block.tpl.php i have 
<?php
if($block->title == 'loginupload')
{
?>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $url?>/loginupload" >
<form>
<?php
}
?>

and loginupload is my module where i m doing the login functionality

Comment: Hey  pamatt I don't know whether i m doing properly or not that's why I would like to share my code with you , if you have prob to share your mail publicly we could talk here rudrajit@esolzmail.com .